# Could not read entity state from ResultSet EntityKey OneToMany chaves compostas

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Estou com problemas no relacionamento oneToMany de duas entidades usando Jpa Hibernate.

Possuo duas tabelas, uma de cancelamento e outra que possui os pedidos que fazem parte do cancelamento.
A tabela de cancelamento possui uma chave primaria simples (idcancelamento)
A tabela de pedidos de cancelamento possui uma chave composta por 4 campos (idcancelamento, codigofilial, pedidovenda, tipopedido), não sei o motivo dessa estrutura, pois é uma base muito grande e que funciona a um bom tempo já.

Então criei uma entidade para a tabela cancelamento com o seguinte relacionamento :

```
@Column
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,  fetch = FetchType.EAGER , targetEntity = Pedido.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "idcancelamento")
private List<Pedido> pedidos;
```

Criei uma entidade para a tabela de pedidos com e a chave composta usando a annotation @IdClass

```
@Id
@Column(name = "idcancelamento")
private Long idCancelamento;

@Id
@Column(name = "codigofilial")
private Long codigoFilial;

@Id
@Column(name = "pedidovenda")
private Long pedidoVenda;

@Id
@Column(name = "tipopedido")
private Integer tipoPedido;
```

Classe da chave composta

```
public class PedidoKey implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 9057318800444577701L;

private Long idCancelamento;
private Long codigoFilial;
private Long pedidoVenda;
private Integer tipoPedido;

public PedidoKey(){

}

public PedidoKey(Long idCancelamento, Long codigoFilial, Long pedidoVenda, Integer tipoPedido) {
    this.idCancelamento = idCancelamento;
    this.codigoFilial = codigoFilial;
    this.pedidoVenda = pedidoVenda;
    this.tipoPedido = tipoPedido;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    PedidoKey taskId1 = (PedidoKey) o;
    if (!idCancelamento.equals(taskId1.idCancelamento)) return false;
    if (!codigoFilial.equals(taskId1.pedidoVenda)) return false;
    if (!pedidoVenda.equals(taskId1.pedidoVenda)) return false;
    return tipoPedido.equals(taskId1.tipoPedido);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(idCancelamento, codigoFilial,pedidoVenda,tipoPedido );
}
```

}

Quando eu faço uma consulta por id e tento acessar a propriedade pedidos da entidade cancelamento o programa lança a seguinte exceção :

```
"error ocurred org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[com.smn.tdc.information.model.Pedido#component[tipoPedido,pedidoVenda,idCancelamento,codigoFilial]{pedidoVenda=403042676, idCancelamento=7662233, tipoPedido=0, codigoFilial=35}]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[com.smn.tdc.information.model.Pedido#component[tipoPedido,pedidoVenda,idCancelamento,codigoFilial]{pedidoVenda=403042676, idCancelamento=7662233, tipoPedido=0, codigoFilial=35}]"
```

Ja mudei o fetch do oneToMany para LAZY, tentei usar @Embeddedid e sempre tenho a mesma excessão.
A unica maneira que ele não deu o erro, foi quando removi as 3 colunas da chave composta e deixei apenas a idcancelamento, mas quando acesso a propiedade ele me retorna apenas 1 resultado, sendo q deveria retornar 14.

Já não sei onde pesquisar mais, tentei de várias maneiras.
Agradeço a atenção e espero que alguem possa ajudar.